# Can I "Add to my calendar" a group event using the Graph API?

Tags: calendar, microsoft-graph-api

In OWA there is a button called "Add to my calendar". This button is visible for all the members of the group even if they have not set as attendees (even if the group itself is not an attendee either).
If a member that is not set as attendee press this button, the member gets the (link of the) event in their personal calendar AND also they get added as an attendee in the group event AND also their attendance is confirmed.

This there a method in the Graph API that is able to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To create an event on a group calendar using graph, send a http request like this: `POST /groups/{id}/calendar/events`. From this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0 Outlook automatically accepts all meeting requests on behalf of groups. You can accept, tentatively accept, or decline meeting requests for user calendars only. For your use case, there currently is no way to have users added as attendees and have their attendance confirmed without their consent.